# HTML form post Vs PHP form post

Tags: java, php, html

I currently have to post HTML form to a java server like ( www.example.com/file.do ).Java server accept only HTML request. So whenever i post request with html file its work fine. But whenever i post it from php its not working ( same html file just change the extension to php). I have also try with mod-rewrite by changing php to html with .htaccess but nothing happen still not works. So i am thinking is there any difference in html form post and php form post? Or is there any other solution so i can post html form through php to java?

Thanks to all.

Comment: Once the PHP is done processing it outputs regular HTML and should have no effect on what the server side code receives.

Comment: Inspect the POST being sent by each script in firebug.  Tweak until they both generate the same POST.

Comment: Actually java server only accept HTML post request. I try to output html from php but not works. Is there anything that i need to tell java server that the post request is coming from HTML post not php post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are posting from localhost. Try to post from a live server. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

technically there is no difference.

Check whether there are some special http headers set, which are not accepted by your server, i.e.

X-Powered-By etc.

Comment: So i need to set specific http headers to send post request from php server? so java server read the post request as html post?

Answer (score 1):

To create a POST request from a PHP script, you need to use [`curl`](http://php.net/curl); but to *submit a form* from the *browser*, it doesn't matter what the extension of the file that is rendered is.

Comment: ok, but can you tell me why the java server not accept php post instead of html one. Although they are the same just the extension change. I need to submit form from the browser.

Comment: There could be many reasons, perhaps there is an extra carriage return or blank space somewhere in the form or the form fields. Since you haven't posted any code, its a guessing game. You should use the developer tools that come with your favorite browser and inspect the headers sent with the request for both forms, that would tell you if there was something different.